# Can't access to my excel workbook anymore after VBA code

Tags: excel, vba

I was trying to search for a code online to automatically close my excel file if the user wasn't active for more than 5 minutes.

I found a code, copied it, and now my workbook/code are locked and can't access to it.

Here is the code I pasted :

```
Private Sub workbook_open()
    starttimer
End Sub

Const idletime = 15 'seconds
Dim start
Sub starttimer()
    start = Timer
    Do While Timer < start + idletime
        DoEvents
    Loop
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ActiveWorkbook.Close True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Open a blank worksheet, go to Options >> Trust center and find the option that disables all macros. Disable them and then remove the code. Stop adding code when you dont understand what it does.

Comment: @braX Thank you. And thanks for your second advice, but that's how I learn!

Comment: Hold down shift while opening the workbook.